# How do I fix the 'TypeError: hasattr(): attribute name must be string' error?

Tags: python, numpy, pymc

I have the following code:

```
import pymc as pm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pymc.Matplot import plot as mcplot
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import rc

res = [18.752, 12.450, 11.832]

v = pm.Uniform('v', 0, 20)

errors = pm.Uniform('errors', 0, 100, size = 3)

taus = 1/(errors ** 2)

mydist = pm.Normal('mydist', mu = v, tau = taus, value = res, observed = True)

model=pm.Model([mydist, errors, taus, v, res])
mcmc=pm.MCMC(model) # This is line 19 where the TypeError originates
mcmc.sample(20000,10000)

mcplot(mcmc.trace('mydist'))
```

For some reason it doesn't work, I get the 'TypeError: hasattr(): attribute name must be string' error, with the following trace:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-49-759ebaf4321c>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/Paul/.spyder2-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Paul/.spyder2-py3')

  File "C:\Users\Paul\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Paul\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 85, in execfile
exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Paul/.spyder2-py3/temp.py", line 19, in <module>
mcmc=pm.MCMC(model)

  File "C:\Users\Paul\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pymc\MCMC.py", line 82, in __init__
**kwds)

  File "C:\Users\Paul\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pymc\Model.py", line 197, in __init__
Model.__init__(self, input, name, verbose)

  File "C:\Users\Paul\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pymc\Model.py", line 99, in __init__
ObjectContainer.__init__(self, input)

  File "C:\Users\Paul\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pymc\Container.py", line 606, in __init__
conservative_update(self, input_to_file)

  File "C:\Users\Paul\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pymc\Container.py", line 549, in conservative_update
if not hasattr(obj, k):

TypeError: hasattr(): attribute name must be string
```

How do I make it work and output "mydist"?

Edit: I posted a wrong trace at first by accident.

Edit2: It all must be because res doesn't have a name, because it's an array, but I don't know how to assign a name to it, so it'll make this work.

Comment: The traceback snippet does not appear to contain that error.

Comment: @Daniel, I posted the wrong one by accident, sorry, I changed it

Answer (score 1):

I must admit that I'm not familiar with *pymc*, but changing it to the following at least made the application run:

```
mydist = pm.Normal('mydist', mu = v, tau = taus, value = res, observed = False)

mcmc=pm.MCMC([mydist, errors, taus, v, res])
```

This seems to be because you were wrapping everything in a *Model* which is an extension of `ObjectContainer`, but since you passed it a list, *MCMC* `file_items` in *Container.py* tried to assign index `4` in a list to something using `replace`, but since `Model` is an `ObjectContainer` it assigned the key `4` in it's `__dict__` causing the weird `TypeError` you got. Removing the wrapping `Model` caused `MCMC` to correctly use an `ListContainer` instead.

Now, there's probably a bug in *Model.py* on [line 543](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/blob/master/pymc/Model.py#L543) where observable stochastics aren't stored in the database - the expression is `for object in self.stochastics | self.deterministics:` but I suspect it should include `self.observable_stochastics` too - so I needed to change `observable` to `False` or the last line would throw a `KeyError`.

I'm not familiar enough with *pymc* to determine if it's actually or bug or desired behaviour so I leave it up to you to submit an [issue](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues) about it.

Comment: im sorry, but this is wrong, because observed = False, means that you don't take res into account, meaning it doesn't look at value (value from expression value = res)

Comment: Sorry, but that is as much as I can do. If `mydist` has `observed` set to `True` you'll get a `KeyError` when trying to extract it's trace.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to define `res` as a numpy array:

```
res = np.array([18.752, 12.450, 11.832])
```

Then you'll get an error here `mcmc.trace('mydist')`because `mydist` is observed data, and therefore is not sampled. You probably want to plot other variables...